# Add space before the anchor tag using Rails link_to and font awesome gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

For some reason I cannot apply CSS to my link_to in order to add spacing for my icon.

I have the following set up in Slim:

```
.col-md-3.offset-md-6.something
 = link_to 'Sign In', 'www.website.com', target: '_blank', id: 'something', class: 'fa fa-lock btn btn-sign btn-md'
```

I've tried the following:

```
#something a::before {
  content: 'f023 \00a0;'
}
.something a::before {
  content: 'f023 \00a0;'
}
.fa-lock {
  content: 'f023 \00a0' !important;
}
```

Since I'm using the font awesome gem I can't target i like referenced elsewhere.

What it actually displays in the page is:

```
<a target="_blank" id="something" class="fa fa-lock btn btn-sign btn-md href="www.website.com">
 ::before
"Sign In"
</a>
```

Heck I even tried using:

```
= link_to '&nbsp;Sign In', 'www.website.com'
```

This just displays the

> & nbsp;Sign In

Comment: have you tried this?

`= link_to ' Sign In', 'www.website.com'`

Answer (score 0):

```
= link_to '&nbsp;Sign In', 'www.website.com'
```

You are passing HTML entity to be rendered. You would have to call `html_safe` on that string:

```
= link_to '&nbsp;Sign In'.html_safe, 'www.website.com'
```

About applying CSS - there is no `a` inside `#something`. There is `a#something`. You can try applying CSS to the `before` by using:

```
a#something::before {
  content: 'f023 \00a0;'
  // your custom CSS
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I actually went all out with all the class and tried a#something .fa .fa-lock .btn .btn-sign .btn-md::before{
    content: "f023 \00a0" !important;
}. Didn't work. Tried the a#something::before. Still didn't work. I did put in link_to '&nbsp;Sign In'.html_safe and that works but that fails my tests.

Comment: If an element has multiple classes/ids, then you have to add them in the CSS without space, like this: `a#something.fa.fa-lock.btn.btn-sign.btn-md::before`. Otherwise, it means: `.btn-md::before inside .btn-sign inside .btn` etc.

Comment: Literally attempted both ways to no avail. Also adding in a simple space adds some distinction but really needs like two/three spaces and can't really get that.

Comment: can you please try this: `a#something::before { margin-right: 1 rem; }`?

Comment: Nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a value for `display`. Also, I think you need to escape the value for your icon glyph:

```
.something a::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '\f023\00a0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So there were a bunch of issues with the font-family being changed and other formatting issues so I ended up with:

```
      .col-md-3.offset-md-6
        = link_to 'www.website.com',
        target: '_blank', id: 'something', class: 'btn btn-sign btn-md', style: 'color:white;' do
       div
        =fa_icon 'lock'
        p[style="display:inline; padding-left:15px;"] Sign In
```

Had to lean into the font awesome gem, apply inline styling as it wasn't being picked up in my SCSS file for whatever reason, and put more styling in the anchor.